# Перевод из 16-ричной системы c#

Tags: c#

На вход (в частности в текстбокс) подается 16-ричное число, с которым нужно выполнить определенные математические действия.Я предполагаю, что для реализации необходимо преобразовать в 10-чную систему.
Суть проблемы заключается в следующем:
 1. Как реализовать защиту от дурака в конкретном данном случае?
 2. Как преобразовать число в 10-чную? Можно при помощи Parse, однако, сможет ли оно конвертировать 16-ричное число с точкой?

Ну и как заключение, может я вижу вопрос не под тем углом и есть решения проще и рациональнее?

Comment: Защита от дурака при вводе: использовать `MaskedTextBox`. А ещё лучше: `NumericUpDown` с установленным свойством `Hexadecimal` в `true`.

Comment: Вам не нужно переводить число из системы в систему. Вам достаточно перевести строку с 16-ричным представлением числа в число.

Comment: _16-ричное число с точкой_ - а разве такие вообще есть?

Comment: Кстати, уточните, что вы используете: WinForms, WPF, а может быть вообще речь о вебе?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov а почему, собственно, не можеть быть вещевственного 16-тиричного числа?

Comment: @max619 - Вещественные десятичные числа (с точкой) в других системах счисления обычно представляют без точки. Я это имею в виду.

Answer (score 2):

Ну вот таким образом можно перевести в 10-чную систему счисления

```
int x = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text, 16);
```

Для числа с точкой можно попробовать переводить по частям, сначала целую часть, потом дробную. А затем записывать в `double`

1 Вариант:

А насчет защиты от дураков, может стоит попробовать чтобы текст в текстбокс вводился не сразу, а считывались клавиши и сверялись с допустимыми символами т.е.

```
Key[] ValidKeys = {Key.D1, Key.D2, ... , Key.Numpad1, Key.Numpad2, ... , Key.A, Key.B, ..., Key.F}
```

А затем кнопка нажатая сравнивались с этим массивом. А только потом символ добавлялся к строке.

Вариант 2:

Создать событие нажатия на клавишу, которое будет сравнивать изменненую строку с первоначальной. И если символ на который она изменилась не входит в диапазон валидных, то присваивать первоначальную строку.

Comment: Проверять нажатые клавиши - в корне неправильный способ! Хотя именно его постоянно советуют (и плюсуют). Реализуйте сами такой способ, после чего вставьте в TextBox неверное значение при помощи Ctrl+C / Ctrl+V - оно не будет отфильтровано.

Comment: А зачем снова в строку преобразовывать, если над int x уже можно производить математические операции?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov тогда второй вариант

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов взял пример кода с левого ресурса, вы правы, надо поправить

Answer (score 0):

По поводу точки, можно использовать что-то вроде этого.

```
String[] hexArray=textbox.text.Split('.');              
// Если у числа есть и дробная и целая часть, то длинна массива будет равна 2.
if(hexArray.Length==2)
{
    // Конвертируем в 10тичную.
    String tmp=Convert.ToInt32(hexArray[0], 16).ToString() + ","  + Convert.ToInt32(hexArray, 16).ToString();               
    // Преобразуем строку Double.
    convertToDouble=Convert.ToDouble(tmp);
}
else
{
    // Иначе, если разделителя не было и число целое то просто конвертируем число.
    String tmp=Convert.ToInt32(hexArray[0], 16).ToString();             
    convertToDouble=Convert.ToDouble(tmp);                  
}
```